# vagrant box add laravel/homestead -–box-version 0.2.7

Tags: vagrant

I have problems with the following command:
vagrant box add laravel/homestead -–box-version 0.2.7 
I installed vagrant 1.7.4 and while trying the command above i have the following error:
An invalid option was specified.

When I try this command(without the version):
vagrant box add laravel/homestead
I have the following error:
box: Loading metadata for box 'laravel/homestead'
    box: URL: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/homestead
Vagrant is attempting to interface with the UI in a way that requires
a TTY. Most actions in Vagrant that require a TTY have configuration
switches to disable this requirement. Please do that or run Vagrant
with TTY.

Please, help me.
Thanks

Comment: In my case, I looked for the latest version which is VirtualBox compatible and I learned that is [6.1.0](https://app.vagrantup.com/laravel/boxes/homestead/versions/6.1.0). So I ran this: vagrant box addd laravel/homestead --box-version 6.1.0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct syntax is

```
vagrant box add --box-version 0.2.7 laravel/homestead
```

or

```
vagrant box add --box-version 0.2.7 laravel/homestead --provider virtualbox
```

to download vagrant box for virtualbox

When running so, you might still face your 2nd issue, there has been [issue](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/6026) reported against vagrant 1.7.4 with [potential fixes](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/6026#issuecomment-126916343) (some say it works, others not)

I will suggest you use latest version of the product which is as of today vagrant 1.8.1, it should fix your issue about the TTY.